# Second-level nesting of objects in Rails 4 failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to build an application with Rails for a running league where I have 3 levels of nesting. I have a Season model which will have 4 Matches, each of which will have 3 races. I am using the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method so that I can use `build`.

I can build 4 matches for a new season through the Season controller but as soon as I try to build a race, my rails server exits with no error message. If I try using the rails console,  I can build Matches for a season and everything saves to the database successfully when the Season is saved.

However, if I do `m = Match.new` I cannot then type `m.races.build` and create a race object - the console exits like the server without any error message. There is no message in the `development.log` either

My models are as follows:

```
class Season < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :matches
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :matches
end

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :season
  has_many :races
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :races
end

class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :match
end
```

In my seasons controller, I have the following:

```
def new
  @season = Season.new
  3.times do
    match = @season.matches.build
    4.times { match.races.build } # comment out this line and the form displays
  end
end
```

I have spent a few hours trying to work out what I'm doing wrong but I'm stumped.

Comment: Are you getting a core dump anywhere? It sounds like ruby is crashing, so I would suspect a problem with a gem, or perhaps a bad ruby install. What ruby version? What platform? What gems are loaded?

Comment: I'm not getting any of the usual Rails verbose trace when you encounter an error. I'm on Windows using ruby 2.0.0-p195 and Rails v4.0.2. This was a brand new app to test that what I want is possible so I haven't yet added anything to the Gemfile.

Comment: I'm not sure how windows logs/records application crashes. Maybe the the event log or something? But if the app and console are shutting down, the most likely ruby itself is crashing (which is both rare and bad). I found this: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8591 Helpful?

Comment: I can't find any log for the ruby application itself. Looks like that bug relates to mySQL2 whereas I'm just using SQLite.

Comment: You won't find a log for this probably. On Mac OS X you'll get an application crash log with (possibly not very useful) details. I'm not sure if windows has anything equivalent. I would honestly try bumping to the latest patch level (ruby-2.0.0-p481) on the off chance you're hitting a bug that's been fixed. But it is very hard to say with this kind of thing. :(